# Removing Rows from Pandas DataFrame based on Multiple Column Values

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to remove rows from a large data frame based on whether each row has certain values in either of two different columns.

I will have a Series called "finalists". Finalists with be a series of names that will be imported from a different part of the code and will change each time its run.

ex)

finalists = ["Company A", "Company F", "Product S"... etc]

The dataframe will be about 1,000 rows long and 200 columns wide

Simplifying it, the dataframe would look something like this:

| category | score | description | company_name | product_name | comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "----" | 2.8 | "----" | Company A | Product A | "----" |
| "----" | 1.2 | "----" | Company B | Product B | "----" |
| "----" | 2.4 | "----" | Company C | Product C | "----" |

I need to keep the rows where either the company_name column or product_name column is one of the values in the Finalists Series (or remove rows where it isn't).

I tried doing something like this:

`results = finalists.isin(app_data["company_name"]) or finalists.isin(app_data["product_name"])`

but got an error that the answer was ambiguous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want something like

```py
mask = app_data["company_name"].isin(finalists) | app_data["product_name"].isin(finalists)

filtered_app_data = app_data[mask]
```

Comment: Perfect Thank You!

Do you know a way to include partial matches?

For example if my Finalist Series had a value of "Company A" but one of the columns contains "Company A, Inc." I'd want to select that row. It looks like currently, these are being left out of its a non-exact match.